# Barra de progreso al estilo youtube, github en angular 4

Tags: angular

Necesito crear o utilizar una libreria de terceros para mostrar una `barra de progreso` al estilo [youtube.com](http://youtube.com) o [github.com](http://github.com) en mi aplicacion `angular 4` cuando realizo peticiones ajax a un servicio web.
Nota:
Trate de utilizar `pace-js` pero se lanzan algunos errores relacionados con el `core de angular 4`

Answer (score 0):

Doy respuesta a mi propia pregunta y la comparto con la comunida.
Aqui les dejo [ngx-progressbar](https://github.com/murhafsousli/ngx-progressbar) un muy buen modulo para mostrar una `barra de carga (loader bar)` en la pagina con `angular 4`.
Este módulo lo puedes personalizar haciendo q captures peticiones automáticas realizadas tanto con `HTTPClient` como con `HTTP`. También se puede iniciar, mediar y finalizar el progreso de la barra a través de un `servicio` que provee el módulo asi como existen otras opciones para cambiar el aspecto de la barra.